# Random Walks - Discrete Probability Question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Could someone help me? I'm not sure how to start

My professor also gave me this hint:

[image]

Comment: "Find the probability that each of the players is the winner". Zero I guess. Only one of them will win (not each of them).

Comment: @drhab Indeed, it was poorly expressed. They likely meant "Find the probabilities, for each player, that they will win the game."

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)
Please use MathJax and see [mathjax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not
viewable to those who use screen readers.  Please read
[this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your
question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ will win the game if:

- $A$ wins on the first throw (with probability of $c_1$), or
- All three players lose on their first throw (with probability of $c_2$), and $A$ wins the remaining game (which, being the same situation as the original game, then has probability of $x$).

Thus the hint: $x=c_1+c_2 x$

Do similarly for the other players.

Comment: What exactly is "c1" and "c2"?

Comment: The probability for these events.  It is up to you to evaluate them from the provided data.

Comment: Well if A throws "one" A wins, so that's a 1/6th probability. B has a 1/3rd chance, and C has a 1/2 chance?

Comment: Yes, that is the data you need to use. @Stuy

Comment: So how do I calculate probability of first throw? I don't know how many throws it'll take until they get the desired number.

Comment: The *first throw* takes one throw; it is the first one, and $A$ goes first. If $A$ wins their first throw, then $A$ wins the game, else $B$ gets to play on the next throw (*their* first throw), and so on. @Stuy  You have already established that the probability that $A$ wins the first throw is $1/6$.  So what is the probability that $A,B,$ and $C$ all loose their first throws?

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to depict the situation by a tree diagram:

\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 A & \stackrel{\frac{5}{6}}{\rightarrow} & B & \stackrel{\frac{2}{3}}{\rightarrow} & C  & \stackrel{\frac{1}{2}}{\rightarrow} & A & \stackrel{\frac{5}{6}}{\rightarrow}\cdots  \\
\frac{1}{6}\downarrow &  & \frac{1}{3}\downarrow & & \frac{1}{2}\downarrow & & \frac{1}{6}\downarrow & \\
W  &  & W & & W & & W & \\
\end{array}

- Let $A,B,C$ denote the events "A wins","B wins", "C wins", resp.: 
  $$P(A) = \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot P(A) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{18} \cdot P(A) \Rightarrow \boxed{P(A)= \frac{3}{13}}$$

For $B$ and $C$ it is a bit different:

- $P(B) = \frac{5}{6}p_B$, where $p_B$ is the probability of $B$ winning, if $B$ had started the game. So,
  $$p_B = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{5}{18} \cdot p_B \Rightarrow p_B= \frac{6}{13}\Rightarrow \boxed{P(B)} = \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{6}{13} \boxed{= \frac{5}{13}}$$
- $P(C) = \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot p_C = \frac{5}{9}\cdot p_C$, where $p_C$ is the probability of $C$ winning, if $C$ had started the game. So,
  $$p_C = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{18} \cdot p_C \Rightarrow p_C= \frac{9}{13}\Rightarrow \boxed{P(C)} = \frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac{9}{13}\boxed{ = \frac{5}{13}}$$

Comment: Nice tree diagram!